# What hostname does npm install point to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to install several Node.js packages through npm on a standalone server that will not be granted direct access to the internet.

I can open up a particular IP Address and port, though.

When one runs 'npm install' from the command line, where is the actual npm repository located, and what port is used by npm to connect to it? npmjs.org, port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This config depends on what is set on `npm config registry` - [by default](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html#registry), it's `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.

You can override it by using `npm set registry <value>`.